# Picker SelectedItem is not being updated when value changes in ViewModel Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, viewmodel, selecteditem, picker

I have ViewModel that should update View's UI Controls in accordance to data from DB. This happens for Entry control being updated correctly but my Pickers don't get updated Selection even if the parameter changes value in ViewModel..

Here is some code from View's Xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="TitleBox" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="Title" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Picker x:Name="TypeCombo" Title="Type" Grid.Row="2" SelectedItem="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding FeaturedType}"/>
```

And ViewModel:

```
    public string Title
        {
            get => _Version.Title;
            set
            {
                if (_Version.Title != value)
                {
                    _Version.Title = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
                }
            }
        }

    public string Type
        {
            get => _Version.Type;
            set
            {
                if (_Version.Type != value)
                {
                    _Version.Type = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Type");
                }
            }
        }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
```

At certain moment in ViewModel the _Version is assigned an object from DB and it's Title and Type are being assigned accordingly.

When the Page finishes loading my UI gets Title updated but the Type from the Picker is not being selected even if the value is correct in ViewModel. Picker remains at -1 (the source items are correct though):

```
ObservableCollection<string> _featuredType;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FeaturedType
    {
        get => _featuredType;
        set
        {
            if (_featuredType != value)
            {
                _featuredType = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FeaturedType");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am losing head here as the ComboBox equivalent in UWP worked without problems but I had to move to Xamarin as I am becoming Android dependant.

This is how I bind to ViewModel:

```
public PageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
BindingContext = this.ViewModel = new PageViewModel();
```

Also, I noticed that doing some test in code behind like so:

```
            string testType = ViewModel.Type;
            string testTitle = ViewModel.Title;
```

returns correct Title value but the Type value results Null even that in ViewModel it was correct.

Comment: When are your picker items loaded? Before or after setting the Type property?

Comment: ItemsSource you mean? The list is populated before the Type and Title are set.

Comment: Did you try setting the ItemDisplayBinding? Also, are all the items loaded and the only problem is the current item selection?

Comment: Yes, everything loads perfectly apart from the pickers. I did not try itemdisplaybinding though

Comment: what should be the ItemDisplayBinding?

Comment: This could be of help to you. Bindable Picker example:  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/BindablePicker/BindablePicker/BindablePicker

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai I have posted my solution that I arrived to thanks to your first comment.

Comment: It seems your picker items weren't loaded before setting the 'Type' property. You could trigger the 'Type' property after setting your picker items as in NotifyPropertyChanged("Type") in the FeaturedType setters.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution, however I am not sure why my previous one did not work.

@Sparsha Bhattarai has put me in the right direction, basically to avoid order problem, I populated ItemsSource from within the Xaml instead of code in ViewModel like this:

```
<Picker.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
        <x:String>Type1</x:String>
        <x:String>Type2</x:String>
        <x:String>Type3</x:String>
    </x:Array>
</Picker.ItemsSource>
```

This has resolved my problem and Pickers are getting correct SelectedItem from ViewModel.

However, this could not be of much of help if I didn't know what the Items are available in Source. Fortunately, in this particular case I can define pickers items beforehand. I would, however like to know why it did not work with code in viewmodel.

Comment: Is your ViewModel inherting the interface INotifyPropertyChanged? I had a similar issue and found out I wasn't inheriting it.